# SQL Server to BigQuery CDC replication

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, cdc

Is there any way to have CDC replication from SQL Server(on-premise) to BigQuery .I can see in GCP documents it is there for MySql ,Oracle and SAP where we can use dataflow or data fusion to achieve same. But I am specifically looking for SQL Server to Big Query.

Any leads will be helpful.

Thanks
Ritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way out using Data-Fusion.
GCP blog [Link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/real-time-cdc-replication-bigquery)

Image for ref.

[image]